# Why G_PRESSED doesn't work in Logitech G HUB?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

After some of the G HUB updates, this script stopped working. Why?

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
PressAndReleaseKey("i")
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GHUB (unlike LGS) `G_PRESSED` event is generated only for G-keys having modified bindings.  The event is not generated for G-keys with disabled binding and for G-keys with standard binding.
In other words, you should modify the standard command assigned to G1 key.
If you want to preserve the original action (pressing of `F1` key) for G1 key, you need to create new macro (something like: press `F1`, wait, release `F1`) and assign it to G1 key.